# Debug Assertion Failed map/set iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have My Map
`std::map<const char*, int> uniforms;`
and when i try to find the data using
`uniforms.find(name)->second`
I get the error stated.
I have checked the data stored in debug mode and it is all there correctly as I expected and i can access most of it using the find function but when I try and access `directionalLight.base.color` I get the error. Like I said they are spelled correctly and there in debug mode but I get the error. Is it the dots in the string?

Answer (score 1):

You might be running past the end of map, so before dereferencing you should check if its valid

```
auto it = uniforms.find(name) ; // or std::map<const char*, int>::iterator it ;

if ( it != uniforms.end() )
{
   // Now use  it->second 
}
```